# GoogleMap, how to remove icons when clicking on the Market en Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps-markers

When I create a marker and click on it, these two icons are shown.
Does anyone know how I can hide the two icons at the bottom right?

[image: picture of a google maps map in a flutter app]

Answer (score 1):

I already found the answer.

```
mapToolbarEnabled: false,
```